# How to defeat Dark Trainer in Pokemon Dusk?

Tags: pokemon-dusk

How do we defeat the Dark Trainer with a team of 6 mews, that too 8x of our levels?
Is there any special move or Pokemon type that should be preferred. I really want to unlock the fossil item.

I am currently able to defeat first 3-4 mews with a team of Gengar, Golett/Golurk with toxic attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark Trainer is one of the elite Pokemon trainer in Pokemon Dusk RPG which indeed require you to have some prep. Items like Pecha Scarf can help you avoid Toxic move from Mew. It also requires TM moves like Toxic. Megahorn, Earthquake, Volt Tackle are the next best moves to use.
You can also teach your pokemon the move Fly, by defeating Zapmulcono (Medium level difficulty). That move will come handy in fights.

Lastly, try to use Rock/Dark pokemon aswell in your team like Tyranitar,

Refer these forums post for more help:
[1]: https://pkmnreborn.com/forums/viewthread.php?id=100
[2]: https://pkmnreborn.com/forums/viewthread.php?id=247

Comment: Thanks man, really helpful. Can this same be applied to defeat the Summer (Poke rpg game ranger)? I believe defeating Summer gives Hyperbeam?